# Display mbfiles in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

I am using Geoserver to host my [mbtiles file](http://ec2-35-180-202-91.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc%3Afichierdeformesdesvoiesdureseauferrenational&bbox=-498694.5095107558%2C5224095.431809284%2C912289.9437286673%2C6634764.392516227&width=768&height=767&srs=EPSG%3A3857&styles=&format=application/openlayers) on EC2. I am trying to open this file in Leaflet but it don't understand how I should set the url.

```
L.tileLayer('http://ec2-35-180-202-91.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc%3Afichierdeformesdesvoiesdureseauferrenational', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
})
.addTo(map);
```

Any clue?

Comment: That's a WMS endpoint, and should be fit for `L.TileLayer.WMS`. Double-check your concepts.

Comment: All right, thanks a lot. I tried with L.tileLayer.wms('http://ec2-35-180-202-91.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS', {} ) but with no success. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/wgX6on6VDOPZKZwC). Do read the [Leaflet WMS/TMS tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html), and be mindful of the [default `L.TileLayer.WMS` options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-wms) and the url-encoding of the layer names (`:` vs `%3a`).

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. Do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, here is a solution that worked. Thank you for the comments.

```
var mapboxurl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.XXXXX';
var mapboxattributes = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' + 'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';

var voiesferrees = L.tileLayer.wms("http://ec2-35-180-202-91.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?", {
    layers: "nurc:fichierdeformesdesvoiesdureseauferrenational",
    format: "image/png",
    transparent: true,
    attribution: mapboxattributes,
    });
```